# PowerBI using SP with multiple selects

Tags: powerbi

I have a `SQL Server` SP that returns 4 datasets.

Is there a way to get the 4 tables in my `PowerBI` query?

> Right now I just see one table.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "returns 4 datasets"? In what form?

Comment: How Power BI could possibly know that your SP returns 4 results? And even if it do knows this, what if on leap years it returns only 3? Or 5? Or swaps the first and last columns of each result? This is a custom logic in your SP. You can't even store these results to tables! You need to modify your SP to store the data in tables and use them in the report.

Comment: @AndreyNikolov thanks a lot it make sense